# How to let users edit R package global variables

Tags: r, package

I'm developing an R package which requires global variables defining the location of 3rd party programs/files. These are currently defined on package load:

```
.onLoad <- function(libname, pkgname){
    options("glob_var1"="default location 1")
    options("glob_var2"="default location 2")
}
```

Users can override these, however, I want organisations/individuals to be able to edit & permanently override this with their own specific defaults.  **What's a good way to achieve this?**

My current solution is to get users to have a configuration file, containing e.g:

```
options("glob_var1"="org default location 1")
options("glob_var2"="org default location 2")
```

And then having users do:

```
library(mypackage)
source("path/to/configuration/file")
```

The downside is users have to source the configuration each time.

Comment: Why not have the package read the config file on load?

Comment: Hmmm... I could request users (via a message) to store the config file in the installed package directory. Then I can source it during .onAttach.  I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: Another way is to put it in the `.Rprofile`, but the options could be overwritten/deleted prior to package loading.